# Is there an official name for the'http://localhost/index.html' part of the url 'http://localhost/index.html?v1=v'

Tags: .net, url, angularjs, uri, query-string

In the interest of good naming, I am trying to figure out what to call the protocol + host + port + path part of a URL.  I am currently using AngularJS and I need to send the path to my SPA to the server so it can generate an email that will allow the user to verify their email address.

I want to make this dynamic.  I could not find a method on $location that would provide this.  I am just wondering if there is an official name for the protocol + host + port + path part of a URL.  In other words, given the following URL's:

```
http://localhost/index.html
http://localhost/index.html?v1=v
http://localhost/index.html#/login
```

Is there a name given to the portion of the URL that is equal to:

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

I originally thought that this would be called the URI, but I can't seem to find any definitive answer to this.  Many references to URI on the Internet as well as the Uri class in .NET include the querystring as part of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

The name, you are looking for, is probably "Base URI".

Here are some links, where it is mentioned.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_APIs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.baseuri(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I think you might be onto something.  When you search for 'baseUri', you mostly get references to XML documentation.  I was hoping to get more confirmation as it relates to RESTful services, but so far it is the best answer I have seen.